# Is making a skill check in place of another check still considered the original skill?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition, skills

I have an ability that allows me to make a "Use the Force" check in place of a "Stealth" check for the purposes of avoiding detection.

Is it still considered a "stealth check" and i am just using my "Use the Force" check bonuses?

Would the check benefit from any bonuses i would normally get to stealth for instance from concealment or equipment modifiers to stealth (from a stealth suit).

Answer (score 6):

Per the text of the talent itself, it is considered training in Stealth, and Stealth rerolls apply to it. Per the FAQ, skill substitutions of this sort count as valid prerequisites for prestige classes (for example, Force Persuasion gets you into Crime Lord). Given this, I would have a hard time denying you concealment or equipment bonuses. For all intents and purposes, it *is* the skill in question.

Comment: Hello, Ephiral, welcome to the site, and +1 for a solid initial answer.  It would be improved slightly if you edited in the relevant text from the talent and Star Wars FAQ.  (On which subject, our [FAQ is here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq) if you'd like to check it out.)

Answer (score 4):

My answer is that **No, it does not count as the same**.  The question is tantamount to asking if Disguise is the same as Stealth, and it is not.  With the Force you aren't concealing yourself, merely altering the willingness of the target(s) to accept that you were seen and incidentally a threat.  While it can still get you past a threat without bloodshed, they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly does count as the same, it explicitly states that with the talent you substitute Use the force for said skill. There are sveeral talents like this and they allow you to act as if you are trained in the skill Use the force is substituting.

You can even ignore situations where you encounter force immune enemies by considering that the force has given the player this skill. This is just arbitrary since the text clearly indicate no circumstance where you lose the ability the talent provides, anyways.